# Inspecting a Http response in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app in which there is a button.
Clicking on this takes the user to a payment site.

There are two use cases(as of now):

1. User hits cancel at payment page

   - in this case the response has two params, status & result, in the URL as query string params.
     In my MVC app I have a ActionResult with two string params which capture this.
2. Transaction is success at the payment page

   - in this the ActionResult does not get hit at all

I can't possibly have different methods for different use cases so wanted to try if it is possible to inspect the response and then do the logic in a single method.

How do I do that in MVC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "inspect the response"? Why would you not have different actions for different use cases? That's exactly what they're there for. If you definitely want the same action, why not use the `status` parameter to signal the desired action? Another thing: is the payment data already on the server or do you still need to post it? If you need to get the data, then you still need another action method...

Comment: _"..I can't possibly have different methods for different use cases"_. Why not? Its normal to have a Delete action to delete something and a Edit action to edit something